# Implementing a direct TCP link between computers hidden by a router with a server managing the connection

Tags: router, nat

I'm working on an encrypted chat program and I'm trying to work out a way of sending messages directly between two computers which are hidden by a router (each have their own local IP address and are NOT port forwarded.) with the connection being managed by a server.

Here is a quick model:

[image: Image model]

```
1. Computer A and Computer B both connect to the server
2. Computer B tells server that it is hosting a session
3. Computer A asks server to join computer B's session

4. Server tells Computer B to accept connections from Computer A - Is this needed?
5. Server tells Computer A how to connect to Computer B

6. Computer A connects to computer B
7. Connection established, able to send TCP messages between computers over stream 
(Could UDP be possible?)
```

My question: is this possible over the internet using NAT? How could it be implemented?

The Answer: Hole punching. Thanks, radicetrentasei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that if I say "peer to peer" you will instantaneously find a solution!

Essentially you are writing a P2P Chat. The problem of NAT with P2P networks has many solutions; to name a few:

- [Port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)
- [Upnp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP)
- [Hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching)

Continue your search with in mind "I want to write a P2P chat" and you will find a lot of documentation.